# What is the mention of Sri Sampradaya in history?

Tags: history, srisampraday

What is the mention of Sri Sampradaya in History?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Maulana Rasheeduddin who was contemporary to Jagadguru Srimad Ramanandacharya, has mentioned Ācharya Charan in his work **'Tajkir-Tul-Fukra'** in 1415 CE. He writes —

❝In Varanasi, on the Panchganga Ghat, there resides a renowned saint who is an embodiment of brilliance and a master of yoga. He is revered as a universally respected Acharya among the Vaishnavites, embodying righteousness and unwavering devotion to the Brahm. He is fully knowledgeable about the secrets of the Supreme Absolute Truth and have a profound impact in the society of true devotees and those who possess the knowledge of the Absolute. He hold the highest authority in matters of religious rituals and practices for Hindus. He only emerge from His sacred cave during the Brahmamuhurta to take a dip in the Ganges. That sacred soul is known as Ramananda. The number of His disciples is more than five hundred (who stays with Him). Amongst that group of disciples, twelve are particularly blessed. They are: 1. Anantanand, 2. Sukhanand, 3. Surasuranand, 4. Naraharyanand, 5. Yogananand (Brahmin), 6. Pipa Ji (Kshatriya), 7. Kabir Ji (Julaha), 8. Sen (Barber), 9. Dhanna (Jat), 10. Raidas (Chamar), 11. Padmavati, and 12. Surasari (Women). The name of this community of devotees is "Vairagi." One who renounces the desires of both this world and the afterlife is called a Vairagi in the language of the Brahmins. It is said that the initiator of this lineage is Sita. She first imparted teachings to Her special servant Hanuman, then that Acharya disseminated this secret (mantra) in the world. **Due to this reason, this lineage is called "Sri Sampradaya"** and their main mantra is known as "Ramataraka Mantra." The sacred mantra is imparted by the Guru into the disciple's ear, and they apply an upward-facing tilak in the shape of a vertical line (Lam) and a horizontal line (Mim) on the forehead, along with other marks on eleven different places. They wrap a diamond-shaped Tulsi bead in the sacred thread (Janeu) and tie it around the disciple's neck. Their tongue is engaged in the continuous recitation of the mantra, while their mind remains absorbed in the contemplation and seeking of their beloved Supreme Being. This lineage is completely devoted to the Supreme Lord. Most of the saints lead a life of self-realization and renunciation, known as the life of a Paramahansa or a wandering ascetic.❞

—Tajkir-Tul-Fukra By Maulana Rasheeduddin (1415 CE), Excerpted from Gita Press Gorakhpur, Kalyan Patrika, Sant Ank.

[image]

[image]

Conclusion we may draw from here:

1. As Maulana Rasheeduddin mentions Lineage of Sri Sampraday starts from Kishori Ji and Kishori Ji gave that mantra to Sri Hanuman Ji which is also mentioned by Sri Hanuman Ji Himself in Vedas;

> तस्याहमिष्टसंसिद्ध्यै **दीक्षितोऽस्मि** मुनिश्वराः ॥ वाञ्छितार्थं
> प्रदास्यामि भक्तानां राघवस्य तु सर्वथा जागरूकोऽस्मि रामकार्यधुरंधरः ॥

Sri Hanuman said: I have taken initiation (Mantra Diksha of Shadakshar Mantra from Sita Ji) and I will fulfill the desires of those who engage in chanting mantras with daily devotion and remember Lord Rāma. I will surely grant the desired objects to the devotees of Sri Ram.

(Atharvaveda Ram Rahasya Upaniṣad 4/12-13)

2. As that Muslim Scholar Maulana Rasheeduddin mentions that Sri Sampraday is the lineage of “Vairagi-s” means one who renounces the desires and they dedicate themselves in the feet of Lord Rama. His talk is absolutely right as Vedas also says so;

> कुण्डिकोपनिषत्ख्यातपरिव्राजकसंततिः । यत्र
> विश्रान्तिमगमत्तद्रामपदमाश्रये ॥

“The community of wandering Ascetics (Sri Sampradaya), well-known for their practice of renunciation, attained their ultimate repose by taking refuge in the feet of Lord Rama."

(Samveda Kundika Upanishad 1.1)

More mentions are present from Vedas that declares the Vedic Authenticity of Sri Sampraday that has a long-standing tradition of ascetics or sannyasis dating back to ancient times.

3. Maulana Rasheeduddin mentions that followers of Sri Sampraday wears Tulsi Mala round their neck.
4. Maulana Rasheeduddin mentions that their mind remains absorbed in the contemplation and seeking of their beloved Supreme Being, Sri Ram, which clears that lineage of Sri Sampraday starts from Lord Sri SitaRam. As previous Acharyas of Sri Sampraday has mentioned that in their works;

> वैदिकः सम्प्रदायः कः कश्च तस्य प्रवर्त्तकः । श्रौतः **श्रीसम्प्रदायः स
> रामसीताप्रवर्त्तितः** ॥३९॥

Jagadguru Dvaranandacharya, Prashnottaravali Shloka 39.

> **"श्रीसम्प्रदायमूलौ च सीतारामौ जगदगुरू ।** नमस्ताभ्यां नमस्ताभ्यां
> नमस्ताभ्यां नमो मनः ॥”

Shri Sitarāmavimshati Jagadguru Haryanandacharya

> "या **श्रियः श्रीस्वरूपा श्रीसम्प्रदायप्रवर्त्तिका** । गुरुणां गुरुवे
> तस्यै **श्रीसीतायै सुमङ्गलम् ॥”**

Sri Sita Mangal Mala By Jagadguru Raghavanandacharya

> “विधेस्तथा च वेदानां सृष्ट्यादौ संविधायकः । ब्रह्मणे वेददाता
> **श्रीसम्प्रदायप्रवर्त्तकः** ॥”

Sri Ram Naam Mala By Maharishi Bodhayan

5. Sri Sampraday is not a Sampraday that has started in 13th century but from the time of Vedas this Sampraday exists. After appearance of Jagadguru Ramanandacharya this sampraday is also known as Sri Ramananda Sampradaya or Sri Ramavata Sampradaya. But historically and according to works of Acharyas and Scriptures this Sampradaya is known as Sri Sampradaya. Scriptures also says that too;

> **रामानन्द इति ख्यातो लोकोद्धरणकारणः।** आचार्यलक्षणैर्युक्तं
> वेदवेदान्तपरागम् ॥ **श्रीसंप्रदायश्रेष्ठञ्च जनोद्धारपरं सदा ।** विज्ञाय
> राघवानन्दं लब्ध्वा तस्मात् षडक्षरम् ॥

Sri Ramananda is known as the cause of lifting the world. He is endowed with the characteristics of acharya and is well versed in the Vedas and Vedanta. He is the great (acharya) of Sri Sampraday and is always devoted to the upliftment of the people. He got Shadakshar Mantra from his Guru Raghavananadacharya Ji.

(-Agastya Samhitā Chapter 132, Shloka 13, 17)

6. Sri Sampraday gives Ram Tarak Mantra in ears during initiation.

Many more conclusions can be drawn but ending up here and leaving all things up to your own wisdom.

Thank You For Reading